# how to exclude the first value of the option in a select

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I have a little problem and i don't know how to fix it.

I have a select like this in my request

```
<select class="form-control" name="start_time" id="time">
      <option>Aanvangstijd *</option>
      <option value="11:00" id="time">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30" id="time">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00" id="time">12:00</option>
</select>
```

But the first option `<option>Aanvangstijd *</option>`  should not pass the validation in my request, but it of course does because it has a value.

Here is my Request

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'msg' => 'required',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'avg' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

So my question is, how can I get it to work that it only passes this validation when an option is passed that isn'tAanvangstijd *`

Comment: make it value empty `value=""` and on validation `nullable`.

Comment: You literally have a validation rule that makes `start_time` required. Check the documentation on the various [Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules), specifically the [`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-nullable) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has great [validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules) so you can be strict and specific about what is allowed in the input, including the [date/time format](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format). From what I see, you expect "start_time" input

- to be [required](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required)
- to be [string](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-string)
- of [5 characters](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-size)
- and to be [valid time](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format).

So, we can write just that:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'msg' => 'required',
        'start_time' => 'required|string|size:5|date_format:H:i',
        'avg' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Maybe you wish to limit the time range between 11:00 and 12:00, or, specifically:

- to be [equal or after](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-after-or-equal) 11:00
- and to be [equal or before](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-before-or-equal) 12:00

So you can add this rules on your validation:

```
'start_time' => 'required|string|size:5|date_format:H:i|after_or_equal:11:00|before_or_equal:12:00'
```

Additionaly you may wish to limit "start_time" [to be only](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-in) 11:00, 11:30 or 12:00:

```
'start_time' => 'required|string|size:5|date_format:H:i|after_or_equal:11:00|before_or_equal:12:00|in:11:00,11:30,12:00',
```

At the and we can increase our readability by using array syntax:

```
public
    function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'msg' => 'required',
            'start_time' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'size:5',
                'date_format:H:i',
                'after_or_equal:11:00',
                'before_or_equal:12:00',
                Rule::in(['11:00', '11:30', '12:00']),
            ],
            'avg' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

And, one advice: TRUST NO ONE, NOT EVEN YOU! Even if you wrote frontend code and (you think) you are 100% sure you know what your html form will be sending your backend, please, use good, strict validation rules.